# Sql select where multiple column no same value on one row

Tags: sql

```
     a b
row1 0 0
row2 1 0
row3 1 1
```

how to select data where a&b ≠ 0 on a row?
I want the result is row2 and row3

Comment: if you want the result to have a != 0 and b != 0, how can you want row2 as results where b = 0 ?!

Comment: sorry,i want the result is a&b on a row ≠ 0

Comment: let me see if I can rephrase. You want to select a and b where a != 0? (if that's the case then this very phrase would already be quite close to the final query)

Comment: @陈梓齐 you want `row3` or `row2 and row3`?

Comment: ok,my question is on the row, i no want to select the data a&b on same row is 0

Answer (score 2):

```
Select
*
from
yourtable
where a <> 0
or b <> 0
```

Comment: The standard in SQL is <>, and this site asks that we use standards (and be consistent in use)

Comment: i think it will select the row2 only

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `tableName` WHERE (a <> 0) OR (b <> 0);
```

Comment: The standard in SQL is <>, and this site asks that we use standards